# How to reset life sales=0 in Magento dashboard?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales, dashboard

I have run below-listed queries:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `gift_message`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `reporting_orders`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_updated`;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

The system doesn't allow me to truncate.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `Mp_sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `Mp_sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `Mp_sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `Mp_sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `Mp_sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `Mp_sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `Mp_sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `Mp_sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `Mp_quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `Mp_quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `Mp_quote_item`;
```

Still, I can't reset the life time sales of Magento 2 dashboard